# OpenID Connect not working with Guacamole

Tags: openid-connect, guacamole

I've included the OpenID Connect extension and added the required properties as outlined in the documentation [here](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/1.0.0/gug/openid-auth.html).  However, when I restart Tomcat I'm still landing on the standard login screen, with no option to authenticate with OpenID.  I also tried removing the MySQL extension to see if that would make a difference, but it did not.

What should be the flow here if OpenID is configured properly and working?  Would there be a separate link for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same issue when configuring Guacamole. In your Guacamole home directory you should have the two directories "extensions" and "lib". Your MySQL connector jar should be in lib, and both the guacamole OpenID and MySQL jar should be in extensions. I renamed the OpenID jar to start with "00-". This change caused guacamole to load OpenID first to serve as the identity provider while still being able to access connection data from the MySQL database.

Comment: Very subtle but right. This took me days to figure out.